# How to prevent duplicate records to be inserted in database using SSIS

Tags: ssis, ssis-2012

I have created SSIS job for inserting records from csv file to sql server database.

if i run the job first time, records are inserted in db successfully, but if i again run the job for second time, again it will store the same records(duplicate).

So if i run my job multiple time , then multiple time records are inserted in db.

> So Is there any way to avoid duplicate records to be inserted in database.?

Answer (score 0):

Please use Look up transformation in SSIS to find out a match in old records and if no match is found then insert that record. Or you can always load the new data to a staging area where you will use CDC(change data capture) to load only unmatched out put through an execute SQL task.

Comment: Its new to me.. Can you please give me some example.?

Comment: @Sanjiv Please use these links for better understanding. For Look up [Link](https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/sql/ssis/implementing-lookup-logic-in-sql-server-integration-services/) And for CDC  [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23373387/ssis-lookup-transform-alternatives).